# RMSE or R squared or others to compare modelled value and observation?

Tags: statistics

I have two data, data A is a modelled temperature data of 365 days and data B is an observed (measured) observation of temperature of the same 365 days. I want to compare the modelled data to the observation and determine how well the model performs. What statistic method is the best? I read that R-squared is only for linear regression ? The temperature data is not linear, it shows seasonality which the summer days are higher. And RMSE only shows the spread of the data, since both modelled and observed data have the same seasonality it shows a low RMSE but the two curves are clearly different. Can you advise what statistics I should use? Thanks.

[This is an example, I want to see how difference is the red and blue line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTGCl.png)

Comment: To an extent, it depends on what you mean by a good fit. You should look at the time series literature for various tests; you may find one that matches your purpose. // It is not true that $r^2$ is only for regression, but $r^2$ measures linear association. // Depending on the appearance of the curves, you might find Spearman's rank correlation useful. // There are goodness-of-fit tests that look at the max difference and others that look at the integral of the absolute difference, but I have seen these used mainly to compare empirical CDFs of _sorted_ data, which would spoil a fit of trends.

Comment: I don't think Spearman rank correlation is appropriate because the data I have is not a ranking or scatter graph. It is temperature (y axis) versus time (x-axis).

Comment: If you want to get into a general discussion of evaluating point forecasts (and which measure of performance makes sense for which statistical functional) I think "Making and Evaluating Point Forecasts" by Tilmann Gneiting (Journal of the American Statistical Association
Vol. 106, No. 494 (June 2011), pp. 746-762) is a very good starting point.